# Disable RGB Camera from Asus Xtion

Tags: bandwidth, asus-xtion

I have an ASUS Xtion Pro Live, and I want to reduce the USB bandwidth requirement down from 70+% down. I noticed that there is an option to reduce this requirement down if I can disable the RGB Camera. Does anybody know how to do this? (e.g. firmware update etc?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have received an official answer from PrimeSense that the best solution is to buy the ASUS Xtion without the RGB Camera. And I also believe the USB3.0 PCI-E expansion card is another solution now.